# Android timezone bug really wierd

Tags: java, android

Anyone can tell me that where the code here give different results?

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(1477785600000l);
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    System.out.println(cal.getTime());
    System.out.println(cal.getTimeInMillis());


    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.setTimeInMillis(1477785600000l);
    cal1.add(Calendar.HOUR, 24);
    System.out.println(cal1.getTime());
    System.out.println(cal1.getTimeInMillis());
```

It works fine server-side but give different results when run on android platform.

Comment: And the Timezone is "GMT"

Comment: Why would they not give different results?

Comment: I think 24hours should equal to 1 day......

Comment: there is an hour gap between the two results.

Comment: ok to get it more obvious, i run the following code:

Comment: I am getting same date for both i.e., Mon Oct 31 05:30:00 GMT+05:30 2016

Comment: `long time = 1477785600000l;
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(time);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        long next = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        long hour = (next - time) / (60 * 60 * 1000l);
 `

Comment: AND result is 25! (GMT set to GMT+0)

Comment: Keep in mind that 1 day is not necessarily equal to 24 hours, i.e. when daylight saving is involved. As an example (not correct, just to illustrate the point) if I'd add 1 day to Oct 31st 2:00 I'd expect to get Nov 1st 2:00, but if I add 24 hours and the dst switch happens at that time I could get Nov 1st 3:00 (or so). - What I mean is that if you add 1 to the "day" field the hour is not changed but if you add 24 to the "hour" field you get a calculation of the day as well (roll over) which might include dst.

Comment: Also note that if the time you're working with is close to a dst switch you might get different results depending on the timezone and the method of calculation. I'm not sure whether this is to be considered a bug or not but that might explain the difference.

Comment: Hi Thomas, theres no dst change. Cost I set the timezone to a specific value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a copy of Thomas's comment.
It's the right answer and thank you all

> Keep in mind that 1 day is not necessarily equal to 24 hours, i.e. when daylight saving is involved. As an example (not correct, just to illustrate the point) if I'd add 1 day to Oct 31st 2:00 I'd expect to get Nov 1st 2:00, but if I add 24 hours and the dst switch happens at that time I could get Nov 1st 3:00 (or so). - What I mean is that if you add 1 to the "day" field the hour is not changed but if you add 24 to the "hour" field you get a calculation of the day as well (roll over) which might include dst.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` instead of `Calendar.HOUR`.
Like this:

```
cal1.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
```

Comment: why? any diffierent?

Comment: @DaisyLi of course it has difference. Look through the docs. HOUR_OF_DAY represents hours from 0 to 23.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same calendar instance to compare the equality of results?

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(1477785600000l);
//add 1 day to the date
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
Log.e("first time", "" + cal.getTime());
Log.e("second time", "" + cal.getTimeInMillis());
//reset the calendar to the instance value removing the day added before
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1); //or you can use cal.setTimeInMillis(1477785600000l);
//add 24 hours to the base calendar value
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 24);
Log.e("third time", "" + cal.getTime());
Log.e("fourth time", "" + cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

And i'm obtaining the same values in the Android Monitor output

```
E/first time: Mon Oct 31 02:00:00 CET 2016
E/second time: 1477875600000
E/third time: Mon Oct 31 02:00:00 CET 2016
E/fourth time: 1477875600000
```

Answer (score -1):

Please look into the Cal.add() method. In the first instance you add month and in the second instance you add hour. Change them and it will work fine.

Please see the documentation link: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getDisplayNames(int, int, java.util.Locale)

You need to use HOUR_OF_DAY for 24hr format. HOUR is  HOUR is used for the 12-hour clock (0 - 11). Noon and midnight are represented by 0, not by 12. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the HOUR is 10 not 22.

Comment: first instance i add one day. and second instance i add 24 hours?

Comment: The problem is not between using HOUR_OF_DAY or HOUR, they both work as expected in this context. You can take the code of my answer and run it with HOUR or HOUR_OF_DAY and you will see they provide the same results.